# Cannot boot from USB at startup

Tags: laptop, usb, bios, dell-xps

Laptop: Dell XPS m1530 with A12 BIOS.

I have USB EMULATION enabled in the BIOS.

At startup, after pressing F12, USB is shown in the list, but I cant boot from it,, boot device gets automatically changed to internal HDD..

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the USB-HDD as the primary boot device.

Also, I want to say that Dell BIOSs treat all bootable harddrives as a single option in the boot order, and then have a secondary list for the boot order of harddrives. You might try modifying the order of that second list if that's the case.

Comment: If you are mentioning boot sequence then i have already made changes in the boot sequence  with usb as the first option

Comment: The A12 bios should not be reverting to your internal UNLESS there is no boot file found and is treating the usb as a slave.  Also this problem is consistant in most legacy boot modes where UEFI will straight tell you if any OS can be found or not.

Answer (score -1):

If you try to install windows 8 it seem you have problem with the secure boot ,this secure boot function work in the `UEFI` BIOS  it preventing  windows from any device than the disk and to make the boot working you must disable it from the BIOS setting  and made the BOIS type `Lagacy` [Secure booting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRz7v.jpg)

Comment: Secure Boot being enabled has nothin to do with the authors problem.  Question was asked more than 3 years before Windows 8.x was even released.